# Robot "should be equal as strings"

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I've got some code in a Robot script that will check a field value is as expected:

```
${search_box}=    Get Value    fullSearchBox
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${search_string}    ${search_box}
```

When I run the script, a failure is recorded against that verification step. However, when I look at the two strings, I can see no differences between them at all (I've also tried using `Should Be Equal`).

If the two strings are the same - why am I seeing this failure?

Comment: Could it be that `Get Value` returns a multiline string? What does `Log To Console   [${search_box}]`and `Log To Console   [${search_string}]` tell you?

Comment: It might be because the strings have different line endings. To help debug this, you might want to print out the length of each string.

Comment: It might be due to space character at end of string

Comment: I tried a .strip() on both the strings. The second appears to have a space at the end, but .strip isn't removing it: "Drawing01; .strip()" Not sure how else I can trim the item retrieved out of the text entry box?

Answer (score 3):

If there is some whitespace on one of the variables, you can strip the whitespace by calling `.strip()` using the [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax):

```
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${search_string.strip()}    ${search_box.strip()}
```